# How to cache a List<T> in a ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, list, caching

I have an **ASP.NET Web Forms** Application.

I have to display search results through a `GridView` control by using as `DataSource` a `List<T>` provided by my **Repository** layer.

Since I use the **autopostback** technique everytime the user changes a search filter, in order to reduce the amount of accesses to the database, I would like to store the initial `List<T>` result set in the cache in order to perform further filtering there.

I found many articles about caching in ASP.NET but all of them were embracing more complex scope than mine. Anybody knows a fast and clear way to do it?

Comment: If you ever want to modify the list, that won't work.

Comment: Did you check ASP.NET's built-in Cache?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing each user will have their own unique resultset, so you could simply store the `List<>` in session.

```
Session[SessionKeys.MyResultsetKey] = myList;
```

Comment: at the moment the list can give a maximum of 280.000 elements. Isn't it too much to be stored in the session?

Comment: Since I have no clue what you're storing in your List or why, it's very difficult to give you advise on how to retrieve or store your dataset.  You asked for advise on how to cache a List, and you have two very good answers, Session or Cache.  If you need further assistance on your overall design, I suggest asking a different question with more detail.

Comment: thanks, yes you are right. The list is composed by T objects with 1 int and 6 strings. May you please enlighten me with the main differences between using Cache and Session?

Comment: Cache is global - all sessions have access to the same data. This space is primarily used for application wide settings or datasets, like a list of States.  Session is private to the current user and used for settings or datasets that are specific to each user, like a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

To store it in Cache you can simply do like this

```
Cache["CacheKeyName"] = myList;
```

For checking if that key already exists on postback you can do like this

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 if(Cache["CacheKeyName"] == null)
 {
  Cache["CacheKeyName"] = myList;
 }
}
```